# Analyzing a trading algorithm

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading

I want to know what are some commons methods/tricks people use to analyze the quality of their trading signals.

Let's say I have a dataframe with all my different signals and their performance. These signals have been executed in different market conditions, on different instrument...

So to understand better on which segment the signals are performing properly and on which segment the signals are performing badly it gets complicated:

- we can first look at the performance on each instrument
- then on each sector
- then on different quantile of market volatility
- then on ...

and then you want to understand what's the performance on combination of the split (on that sector when the volatility is bigger than...).

So more generally when you want to analyze your trading signals based on a number of $n$ factors how do you go about getting a better understanding of: in which conditions the signal perform well and in which conditions does it perform badly?

Because the problem I am facing is that the number of segments to analyze can be extremely large so I get lost very easily in the analysis, and also when can you consider that would you observed is statistically significant and is not just "chance".

Comment: all I can say is that, if you break things down too finely, you'll find some kind of pattern ( say some kind of pattern in sector performance ) and that will cause you to possibly use sector-specific parameters since the sector performance varies. But I would be careful about doing things like that because it can lead to data mining-overfitting. Sometimes, the most general parameter is the most stable.